# Is there a way to execute a function after an animation in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift5, xcode11

In UIKit you can do something like this:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval, animations: {
    //animation
  }) { (Bool) in
    //code which will be executed after the animation
}
```

Is there anything like that in SwiftUI, or can you think of a replacement?

Comment: Check [this link](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-an-explicit-animation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an approach to this described here:

https://www.avanderlee.com/swiftui/withanimation-completion-callback/

The approach requires the use of a custom implementation of the `AnimatableModifier` protocol. It's not completely trivial to implement, but it does seem to solve the problem.